# How to format text from the DB before showing on a Website

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a mysql database that contains fields with paragraphs of text that i want to show on my website. I have a normal textbox where i put text and send to the database, however when i read the data on my website the text is not proparly formatted.

How do i make sure that when i access the data from my website it comes properly formatted. Is there a textbox that saves the data in he mysql database such that when i consume it from the website it gets properly formatted on my website.

I am using html and php on my website.

Comment: You could use a WYSIWYG or use http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php, depends how much detail you want in the formatting.

Comment: So the problem is i want other users to be able to post on my blog/website so i want them to post without having to write html tags in the text. Something like what happens with a comment box

Comment: Yes, so either option I provided would work for that. `nl2br` would maintain newlines. `WYSIWYG` would write the HTML as the user formats it. Look out for XSS injections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a WYSIWYG (What You See Is What You Get).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG

This will turn a regular form textarea input in to an input that allows formatting.
Take a look at TinyMce and CKEditor.

https://ckeditor.com/

https://www.tinymce.com/